# ¿Cómo ejecutar formulario rellenando con la barra de búsquedas del navegador el método POST?

Tags: javascript, php, html

¿Cómo puedo ingresar a esta página web tipo formulario (no se si es php) sin tener que rellenar un una etiqueta tipo `<form>` con método POST?. Necesito escribir en el navegador la pagina web con el formulario ya rellenado y que me devuelva el resultado:

```
<form method="post" action="https://nosetup.org/php_on_line/descargar">
Dirección:
<input type="text" name="pagina_web" value="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada" size="50" />
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Descargar página" />
</form>
```

O sea, quiero que sea algo así:

https://pagina.php?variableUno=valorUno&variableDos=valorDos&variableTres=valorTres

Pero con mis datos y que funcione al ponerla en la barra de búsquedas del navegador:

https://nosetup.org/php_on_line/descargar?pagina_web=https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia

Lo que quiero es que se cargue la pagina ya rellenada directamente parecido a esto:

```
<body onload="document.forms['miformulario'].submit()">
<form  name="miformulario" method="post" action="https://nosetup.org/php_on_line/descargar">
Dirección:
<input type="text" name="pagina_web" value="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada" size="50"/>
<input "type="submit" name="enviar" value="Descargar página" />
</form>
</body>
```

Es decir, que haga eso pero sin redireccionar, o sea, que al cargar la pagina ya cargue con los datos del formulario directamente como si fuera un link del navegador.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que hacerlo con `GET`, no con `POST`:

**formulario**

```
<form method="get" action="pagina.php">
    Dirección:
    <input type="text" name="pagina_web" value="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada" size="50" />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Descargar página" />
</form>
```

**destino (pagina.php):**

```
<?php

// Resultado de pagina.php?pagina_web=https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada:

print_r($_GET['pagina_web']); // Imprime 'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada'
```

Comment: no  tiene sentido esta respuesta

Comment: lo que quiero es rellenar este formulario desde la barra de busquedas del navegador

Comment: Tu quieres escribir una URL con parámetros para luego trabajar con ellos, ¿no?

Comment: si, claro quiero dejarlo como una url para usarlo con google apps script y hacer raspado web de webs que usan anti bots

Comment: Pues entonces SÍ tiene sentido. Tienes que utilizar el método GET, no POST, tanto en el formulario que utilices como a la hora de recoger los parámetros.

Comment: La edito con el formulario, a ver si lo ves más claro.

Comment: haber yo no soy el autor de esta pagina

Comment: https://nosetup.org/php_on_line/descargar

Comment: lo que quiero es hacer algo asi con google apps script

Comment: var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://nosetup.org/php_on_line/descargar?pagina_web=https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia");

Comment: Entonces está mal formulada es la pregunta. Mi respuesta está planteada para PHP, lenguaje que has incluido en las etiquetas, no para Google Apps Script, y explicando cómo enviar las variables desde el navegador para luego trabajar con ellas.

Comment: y lo repito yo no soy el autor de https://nosetup.org/php_on_line/descargar por tanto no puedo editarla, solo quiero rellenarla sin usar el formulario, osea solo como si fuera un link interactivo que puedo modificar la respuesta

Comment: se puede enviar los datos con método post como si fuera un link, o es imposible?, como dije yo no soy el creador del php por tanto no puedo modificarlo

Comment: te doy un positivo por que creo que tienes razón en lo de que si no es get, no se muestran los datos que se envían al servidor en la misma dirección URL